# Till when an accepted vote can be changed?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

Let's say one user asked a question and got two/three answers. Later he accepted one of the answers.

Now can he change his accepted vote? If so, is there any time limit? Please explain if same rule is applicable for Up-Vote and Down-Vote.

**Note**: Provided neither question nor answer is edited.

Comment: There is not time constraint for changing an acceptance vote. You can change whenever you want.

Comment: @Pandya What about Up-Vote and Down-Vote?

Comment: Have you visited the link posted in answer?

Comment: @Pandya Not earlier.. now visited...no more doubt.. :) :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/260388) :

> **Accepting**
>
> - All must wait 15 minutes after asking to accept any answer
> - All must wait 48 hours after asking to accept own answer
>
> **Voting**
>
> - 30 votes per day +10 for questions only (Q only votes can't be used after 25 votes cast on answers. Source)
> - If you vote and undo your vote 30 times, your vote gets locked in.

Regarding your question on changing votes on others' answers, there is not time constraints, you can change acceptance vote any time from one answer to another or unaccept the answer anytime. Just note that you've to wait for 15 minutes in case of new answer.